# Canonical name for the partition that a partition of a set induces on its subsets

Tags: set-theory, set-partition

Assume we have a partition $\mathcal{F}$ of a set $E$ and $X\subset E$ is there a canonical name for

$$\mathcal{G} = \{X\cap A|A\in \mathcal{F}\} $$

?

I'd say *induced partition* but it is a bit of a mouthful, or *trace*, borrowing from filters/filtrations, but I'd like to know if it already has another name.

Bonus points : if $X\not\subset E$, how would you call

$$\mathcal{G}' = \{X\cap A|A\in \mathcal{F}\} \cup \{\{x\}|x\in X\smallsetminus E\}$$

?

---

<sub>If anyone wonders where this comes from, the notion appears in some [clustering quality metrics](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P14-2006) for NLP</sub>

Comment: I don't think "induced partition" is such a mouthful, personally. And it intuitively means exactly what you want it to mean.

Comment: An alternative is to call $\mathcal{G}$ the *restriction* of $\mathcal{F}$ to $X$.